# How can I create tables that support associating multiple items with a single invoice?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to make a basic invoicing project in C#. I want to create a table tblSales that will have all the details of a sales invoice. If a user wants a single item then its ok but if user wants to add multiple items then how to update the table accordingly? I have a table tblItems that has details about item like id,name,qty etc.

Comment: Your question is way too broad.  Although a C# application can access data in a database, it doesn't have any type of database built in to it.  You need to decide what type of database is going to hold your information (SQL Server, MS Access, MySQL, MongoDb, etc) and then that choice will dictate how you create tables and how you interact with them using C#.

Comment: @dazedandconfused The question has tags including "sql-server". They originally had "C#" and "sql". This makes it pretty clear that they are using Microsoft SQL Server, at least in my opinion. The question is specific as well, because they are asking about how to accomplish implementing a set of tables that allows for a one to many relationship, not a wide range of problems or how to implement a broad or subjective concept such as "How can I make this nice?" Based on this, I respectfully disagree with your comment and all recommendations to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a table that lets you relate many items to one invoice; they're typically called line items.

I would start with your invoice table, looking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Invoice]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [Title] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);
```

Afterward, you need a way to store line items. This is done by adding a foreign key from one table to another. Each invoice item is foreign keyed into an invoice, thus creating a relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE [InvoiceItem]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceId] BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Invoice]([Id]) NOT NULL,
    [Name] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [Total] SMALLMONEY NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);
```

With a structure like this, you would typically create an invoice by first starting a transaction, inserting an invoice, and then inserting the invoice items for that invoice, finally committing the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need a third table called `tblSaleItem`.

This would need the columns: `ID, SaleID, and ItemID`.

If a sale buys 4 items, there will be one row in `tblSale` for the transaction, and four rows in `tblSaleItem` for each of the 4 items purchased. Each item will have a `SaleID` mapping to the same `tblSale` row.

Hopefully that all makes sense. This is called normalizing a database.